# How do I implement infinite voxel chunks without slowing down the performance in c++?

Tags: c++, sfml

So I'm currently working in a chunk with a size of 16x256x16 and create a integer grid for block types. But my problem is how do I implement infinite voxel chunks???
I use SFML 1.6 by the way.

Here is my code:

Header (chunk.hpp):

```
#ifndef CHUNK_HPP
#define CHUNK_HPP

#pragma once
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "player.hpp"
#include "types.hpp"
#include "frustumcull.hpp"
#include "noise_generator.hpp"

const int horiz_chunksize = 16;
const int vert_chunksize = 256;

class Chunk {
public:

    Chunk();
    ~Chunk();

    int get(int x, int y, int z); // get block type in position
    void set(int x, int y, int z, int type); // set block type in position
    void render(Player &p, FrustumCull &cull, int renderDistance = 20); // render chunk
    int getTerrainHeight(int x, int y); // returns noise height on the given position

private:

    Perlin_Noise m_noise;
    void update(int x, int y, int z, int type); // update block faces
    
};

#endif // CHUNK_HPP
```

Source (chunk.cpp):

I put the m_blockgrid in .cpp because if I put it in the header it will
only draw one cube and also does in Chunk::~Chunk() delete[] chnk::m_blockgrid necessary???

```
#include "chunk.hpp"
#include "block.hpp"
#include "maths.hpp"
#include <iostream>

namespace chnk {
    int m_blockgrid[horiz_chunksize][vert_chunksize][horiz_chunksize]; // block grid
    Block *m_block;
}

Chunk::Chunk() {
    chnk::m_block = new Block(); // initialize block class
    m_noise.setSeed(sf::Randomizer::Random(2736473, 8476864));

    for(int x = 0; x < horiz_chunksize; x++) {
        for(int z = 0; z < horiz_chunksize; z++) {
            int heightmap = 16;
            for(int y =-1; y < heightmap; y++) {
                if(y > heightmap-2) set(x, y, z, BlockType::GRASS);
                if(y < heightmap-1 && y > heightmap - 4) set(x, y, z, BlockType::DIRT);
                if(y < heightmap-3 && y > 0) set(x, y, z, BlockType::STONE);
                if(y == 0) set(x, y, z, BlockType::BEDROCK);
            }
        }
    }

}

Chunk::~Chunk() {
    delete[] chnk::m_blockgrid;
}

int Chunk::get(int x, int y, int z) {
    // check boundary
    if((x<0) || (x>=horiz_chunksize) ||
       (y<0) || (y>=vert_chunksize) ||
       (z<0) || (z>=horiz_chunksize)) return BlockType::AIR;
    return chnk::m_blockgrid[x][y][z];
}

void Chunk::set(int x, int y, int z, int type) {
    chnk::m_blockgrid[x][y][z] = type;
    m_update = true;
}

void Chunk::render(Player &p, FrustumCull &cull, int renderDistance) {
    int px = p.m_position.x / chnk::m_block->m_size;
    int py = (p.m_position.y + p.m_bottom) / chnk::m_block->m_size;
    int pz = p.m_position.z / chnk::m_block->m_size;
    float radius = sqrt(Maths::sqr(chnk::m_block->m_size) * 5);

    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE); // hide back face
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); // depth testing

    // render object(s)
    for(int x = 0; x < horiz_chunksize; x++) {
        for(int z = 0; z < horiz_chunksize; z++) {
            for(int y = 0; y < vert_chunksize; y++) {
                int type = get(x, y, z);
                if(!cull.sphereInFrustum(sf::Vector3f(chnk::m_block->m_size * x + chnk::m_block->m_size / 2, chnk::m_block->m_size * y + chnk::m_block->m_size / 2, chnk::m_block->m_size * z + chnk::m_block->m_size / 2), radius)) continue;
                update(x, y, z, type); // update for block texture & etc.
            }
        }
    }
}

void Chunk::update(int x, int y, int z, int type) {
    // only show face in outside not inside
    // I use get(x, y, z) to get block position at given grid
    if(BlockType::getSolidBlocks(type)) {
        if(BlockType::getSolidBlocks(get(x, y+1, z)) == 0 && get(x, y+1, z) != type) {
            chnk::m_block->setupBlock(x, y, z, Block::Top); // Top Face
        }
        if(BlockType::getSolidBlocks(get(x, y-1, z)) == 0 && get(x, y-1, z) != type) {
            chnk::m_block->setupBlock(x, y, z, Block::Bottom); // Bottom Face
        }
        if(BlockType::getSolidBlocks(get(x, y, z-1)) == 0 && get(x, y, z-1) != type) {
            chnk::m_block->setupBlock(x, y, z, Block::Front); // Front Face
        }
        if(BlockType::getSolidBlocks(get(x, y, z+1)) == 0 && get(x, y, z+1) != type) {
            chnk::m_block->setupBlock(x, y, z, Block::Back); // Back Face
        }
        if(BlockType::getSolidBlocks(get(x-1, y, z)) == 0 && get(x-1, y, z) != type) {
            chnk::m_block->setupBlock(x, y, z, Block::Left); // Left Face
        }
        if(BlockType::getSolidBlocks(get(x+1, y, z)) == 0 && get(x+1, y, z) != type) {
            chnk::m_block->setupBlock(x, y, z, Block::Right); // Right Face
        }
    }
}

int Chunk::getTerrainHeight(int x, int y) {
    return ( m_noise.getHeight(x, y) + 64 ); // total height of the given coordinates
}
```

Some people uses unordered_map to store loaded/unloaded chunk but I dont know how to use it and if it does work??

Anyone would like to help me?? :)

Comment: Welcome @rentheprogrammer. 
What exactly do you mean by "without slowing down": Do you want to access a chunk in O(k)? do you want to access a particular block inside a given chunk in O(k)? How big is "Infinite"?

Comment: m_update is not included in the code btw sorry. :)

Comment: @AdrianMaire What is O(k)?

Comment: "Big O" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) is a notation to indicate how fast is an algorithm given an imput. O(k) means whatever is the input, it returns in constant time, O(n) means linear (like iterating all elements), O(n^2) is ... you got it right?

Comment: @AdrianMaire I dont really knew about any algebratic formula, but yeah I got it thanks.

Comment: `delete[] chnk::m_blockgrid;` is the opposite of necessary, it is undefined behaviour. Unless you use `new`, do not use `delete`. `Block *m_block;` is likely wrong too, it is a global variable, shared by all `Chunk` objects, this is the likely reason why only one chunk go drawn. What is even the point of `chnk`  namespace?

Answer (score 1):

I will make the following suppositions:

1. Access to a given chunk is the priority, they are accessed several times a frame so access needs to be O(k)
2. Insertion and deletion of chunks needs to be done as fast as possible, because they will be generated on the fly, and dropped on the fly. Not as critical as the access.
3. Most of the time, the amount of chunks in memory is about constant.

Now, let see what are our possibilities:

| `std::` container | Insertion | Access | Erase | Find | Persistent Iterators |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `vector`/ `string` | Back: O(1) or O(n) Other: O(n) | O(1) | Back: O(1) Other: O(n) | Sorted: O(log n) Other: O(n) | No |
| `deque` | Back/Front: O(1) Other: O(n) | O(1) | Back/Front: O(1) Other: O(n) | Sorted: O(log n) Other: O(n) | Pointers only |
| `list`/ `forward_list` | Back/Front: O(1) With iterator: O(1) Index: O(n) | Back/Front: O(1) With iterator: O(1) Index: O(n) | Back/Front: O(1) With iterator: O(1) Index: O(n) | O(n) | Yes |
| `set`/`map` | O(log n) | - | O(log n) | O(log n) | Yes |
| `unordered_set`/ `unordered_map` | O(1) or O(n) | O(1) or O(n) | O(1) or O(n) | O(1) or O(n) | Pointers only |
| `priority_queue` | O(log n) | O(1) | O(log n) | - | - |

`std::unordered_map` is the most adequate structure for this because it allows constant access, and (most of the time) constant insertion/deletion:

```
struct ChunkCoordinate
{
    int32_t x,
    int32_t y
};
class ChunkCoordinateHash{
public:
    size_t operator()(const ChunkCoordinate &val) const
    {
        static_assert(sizeof(size_t)==8);
        return (static_cast<size_t>(val.x)<<32ull) + (static_cast<size_t>(val.y)&0xffffffff);
    }
};

std::unordered_map<ChunkCoordinate, unique_ptr<Chunk>, ChunkCoordinateHash> m_chunks;
```

Note: Insertion and Erase on `unordered_map` is usually `O(k)`(constant), unless space is missing and all the map needs to be relocated. as you have usually a constant number of chunks loaded, you can `unordered_map::reserve` a sufficient amount of chunks so that it is never relocated.

Note2: I use pointers to `Chunk` to make any relocation faster.

Here is some example of usage:
https://onlinegdb.com/FiGzEzHgD

Comment: I made a markdown version of the big-O table. Would you mind if I put it in?

Comment: Cool. I'll leave your original in there so it's easy to spot if I made any errors. Edit: Hmm - it doesn't look as nice as it did when I edited it :-/ Oh, well, if you think it's too messy you can always rollback. :)